# Default instance of RoutingSearchParameters not working

Tags: or-tools

I cannot run a solution with routing parameters because the method does not accept the default RoutingSearchParameters because the instance is empty (every field is set to 0).

Here is how I'm creating the instance:

```
// final var p = RoutingSearchParameters.newBuilder().build(); Both don't work
final var p = RoutingSearchParameters.getDefaultInstance();
final var s = routing.solveWithParameters(p);
```

Here is the error (happens for every single field):

```
E0717 20:27:26.682358  6108 routing.cc:1886] Invalid RoutingSearchParameters: Invalid cheapest_insertion_first_solution_neighbors_ratio: 0
```

Is there any way to solve it without manually setting every field?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp#java_4 ?

Comment: @Stradivari the documentation doesn't show how the defaultRoutingSearchParameters method is defined.

Comment: you have to import it: `import com.google.ortools.constraintsolver.main;`, if you need the cpp source code, see Laurent's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by a comment: the proper way to instantiate the RoutingSearchParameters class is by importing `com.google.ortools.constraintsolver.main` and then use the method `main.defaultRoutingSearchParameters()`.

Answer (score 1):

All parameters default are visible here:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/45770b833997f827d322e929b1ed4781c4e60d44/ortools/constraint_solver/routing_parameters.cc#L45

```
      "first_solution_strategy: AUTOMATIC "
  "use_unfiltered_first_solution_strategy: false "
  "savings_neighbors_ratio: 1 "
  "savings_max_memory_usage_bytes: 6e9 "
  "savings_add_reverse_arcs: false "
  "savings_arc_coefficient: 1 "
  "savings_parallel_routes: false "
  "cheapest_insertion_farthest_seeds_ratio: 0 "
  "cheapest_insertion_first_solution_neighbors_ratio: 1 "
  "cheapest_insertion_ls_operator_neighbors_ratio: 1 "
  "local_search_operators {"
  "  use_relocate: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_relocate_pair: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_light_relocate_pair: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_relocate_subtrip: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_relocate_neighbors: BOOL_FALSE"
  "  use_exchange: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_exchange_pair: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_exchange_subtrip: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_cross: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_cross_exchange: BOOL_FALSE"
  "  use_relocate_expensive_chain: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_two_opt: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_or_opt: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_lin_kernighan: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_tsp_opt: BOOL_FALSE"
  "  use_make_active: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_relocate_and_make_active: BOOL_FALSE"  // costly if true by default
  "  use_make_inactive: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_make_chain_inactive: BOOL_FALSE"
  "  use_swap_active: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_extended_swap_active: BOOL_FALSE"
  "  use_node_pair_swap_active: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_path_lns: BOOL_FALSE"
  "  use_full_path_lns: BOOL_FALSE"
  "  use_tsp_lns: BOOL_FALSE"
  "  use_inactive_lns: BOOL_FALSE"
  "  use_global_cheapest_insertion_path_lns: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_local_cheapest_insertion_path_lns: BOOL_TRUE"
  "  use_global_cheapest_insertion_expensive_chain_lns: BOOL_FALSE"
  "  use_local_cheapest_insertion_expensive_chain_lns: BOOL_FALSE"
  "}"
  "relocate_expensive_chain_num_arcs_to_consider: 4 "
  "heuristic_expensive_chain_lns_num_arcs_to_consider: 4 "
  "local_search_metaheuristic: AUTOMATIC "
  "guided_local_search_lambda_coefficient: 0.1 "
  "use_depth_first_search: false "
  "use_cp: BOOL_TRUE "
  "use_cp_sat: BOOL_FALSE "
  "continuous_scheduling_solver: GLOP "
  "mixed_integer_scheduling_solver: CP_SAT "
  "optimization_step: 0.0 "
  "number_of_solutions_to_collect: 1 "
  // No "time_limit" by default.
  "solution_limit: 0x7fffffffffffffff "             // kint64max
  "lns_time_limit: { seconds:0 nanos:100000000 } "  // 0.1s
  "use_full_propagation: false "
  "log_search: false "
  "log_cost_scaling_factor: 1.0 "
  "log_cost_offset: 0.0";
```